# ResponsiveSlides.js custom mouseover controls and other functionality

Tags: jquery, responsive-slides

I'm trying to get ResponsiveSlides.js set up with some custom functionality. I need to be able to use the slider with manual controls that work on mouseover instead of click but go to specific url links on click. I will have four slides in the slideshow and need to be able to navigate them using the four buttons. Here is what I want to achieve:

1. Have my four buttons work on mouseover instead of click. I am using 'manualControls: ".custom-pagers",' to implement custom navigation. I was wondering if there is a way to navigate to my specific slides on mouseover but have it go to the `href=""` url on click.
2. Have another separate button (`.buy-tag a`), pause the slider on mouseover but go to the `href=""` URL on click.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {

  // Slideshow 1
  $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
    speed: 800,
    manualControls: ".custom-pagers", 
  });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
    <!-- SUPER SLIDER -->
    <div class="rslides_container">

    <div id="main-featured" class="twelve columns">  

    <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
      <li><div id="img-featured" class="five columns"><a href="http://www.domain.com/"><img src="http://www.domain.com/images/image1.png" alt=""></a></div>
         </li>

      <li><div id="img-featured" class="five columns"><a href="http://www.domain.com/"><img src="http://www.domain.com/images/image2.png" alt=""></a></div>
        </li>

      <li><div id="img-featured" class="five columns"><a href="http://www.domain.com/"><img src="http://www.domain.com/images/image3.png" alt=""></a></div>
        </li>

    </ul>


    </div>


    </div><!-- /SUPER SLIDER -->

    <div class="full-row green-mid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="types-tag" class="four columns">
                <h3>What type are <strong>YOU</strong>?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="eight columns">
                <ul class="custom-pagers">
                <li><div class="straight-tag"><a href="http://www.domain.com/link1"><span>1</span> Straight</a></div></li><li><div class="curly-tag"><a href="http://www.domain.com/link2"><span>3</span> Curly-Kinky</a></div></li>
                <li><div class="wavy-tag"><a href="http://www.domain.com/link3"><span>2</span> Wavy-Curly</a></div></li><li><div class="kinky-tag"><a href="http://www.domain.com/link4"><span>4</span> Kinky-Coily</a></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

<div class="buy-tag"><a href="http://www.domain.com/buy"><span><strong>Buy</strong> Now</span></a></div>
```

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance!